# DOMSource remains empty for String to XML

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I am trying to generate XML file from String using DOMParser. The code snippet is like this:

```
public class SomeClassToSendString () 
{

    private XMLBuilder xmlBuilder;

    public SomeClassToSendString(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        xmlBuilder = new XMLBuilder(fileName)
    }

    public void writeHeader{
        xmlBuilder.writeRootElements(); }
    public void writeRecords(String record){
       xmlBuilder.writeRecords(record); }
    public void close{
        xmlBuilder.close() }
}

public class XMLBuilder {
    private String fileName;
    private DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory;
    private DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
    private Document document;
    private Element rootElement;
    private Element childOfRoot;

    public XMLFileHandler(String fileName) throws ParserConfigurationException {

        this.fileName = fileName;
        docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = docBuilder.newDocument();
    }

    public void writeRootElements() throws AppException{

        try {
            // root element
            rootElement = document.createElement("root");
            document.appendChild(rootElement);

            // child element
            childOfRoot = document.createElement("childOfRoot");
            rootElement.appendChild(childOfRoot);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
    public void writeRecords(String string) {
        Element childOfFirstChild = document.createElement("childOfFirstChild");
        childOfRoot.appendChild(childOfFirstChild);
                Element record = document.createElement("record");
        record.appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));
        childOfFirstChild.appendChild(record); }

    public void close() {
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult xmlResultFile = new StreamResult(new File(fileName));

        transformer.transform(source, xmlResultFile); }
}
```

The Document remains null so in turn the DOMSource is empty. I am unable to figure out where am I going off track. 
Thanks.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that, other than the misnamed constructor, your horrendous indentations, and excessive use of fields for values that could just be variables. I tested by replacing `new File(fileName)` with `System.out`, then exercising the builder using `XMLBuilder xml = new XMLBuilder(null); xml.writeRootElements(); xml.writeRecords("Hello"); xml.writeRecords("World"); xml.close();` and got some nice XML printed.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for getting back and I apologize for the indentations. For some reason its still returning empty. I replaced the DOM parser by using simple StringBuilder and then writing out to file. If you can please take time to answer this, is it a good practise to use StringBuilder over the DOM Parser? I am getting my work done, but just for the knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to build the XML yourself, you can, but you should create a buffered writer on the file and write the XML directly, instead of using a StringBuilder. Just make **sure** you specify the right file encoding (usually UTF-8), and escape all special characters (`& < > ' "`) in text values. --- Better yet, instead of manual XML or DOM XML, use a StAX writer. See here for example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/stax-xmlstreamwriter.html